# R*-Tree C Implementation?

Tags: c, implementation, r-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ R - tree implementation wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709339/c-r-tree-implementation-wanted)

I've been hunting just about all evening...

Anyone know of a R*-Tree implementation that builds on a modern C compiler?

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but why is this a duplicate? I'm also looking for a solution for C and I'm not really interested in C++ implementations.

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite's](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) R* Tree might interest you.  It is under [public domain or such free license](http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html) and builds with gcc.